# Get rid of bash login message after Linux Brew uninstall

Tags: linux, homebrew, linuxbrew

I removed brew on Linux but still get the following message every time I log in:

```
-bash: /home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew/bin/brew: No such file or directory
```

How do I remove it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you followed [this installation guide](https://docs.brew.sh/Homebrew-on-Linux), you need to find the `.profile` file which you added that directory and remove it.

For me it was at `$HOME/.profile`. Once I removed that entry, the message is now gone.